# How to specify a database engines in pom.xml in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, jpa

I am writing a server application using Spring Boot that connects to a database. The application uses Hibernate / JPA and should support multiple DB engines, ideally just by configuring the Spring Boot properties (`spring.datasource.*`).

Currently, it supports only MySQL and in order for the support to work out of the box, I have added this dependency in my pom.xml file, as suggested in many SO questions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

What is the cleanest way to support multiple DB engines? Should I:

- Include all engine dependencies I would like to support as runtime dependencies in pom.xml? (seems too "chatty", manual and incomplete)
- [edit] Add some unifying dependency that already has the up-to-date list of database engines? (I cannot find one)
- Not include any dependency in pom.xml and ask an application deployer to do an additional server configuration in order to have the correct engine libs on the classpath? (seems as unnecessarily complicated step to ask from the deployer)
- Any other way to do this in a clean manner?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to answer with my solution: I actually talked to the customers to see what they think about this. As it turns out, all of them already have a DB driver on their server's classpath, therefore the option "Not include any dependency in pom.xml ..." seems to be correct for my case. Customers of my software are banks, it will likely be different for other types of customers.

Answer (score 0):

What is your use case that requires multiple database connections?  I would be tempted to create multiple Repository Configuration files, e.g. from http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-java-configurations/

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mobapp.repository")
public class DataBaseConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

            return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

            return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
            properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
            return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
            return transactionManager;
    }
```

}

Comment: I don't need multiple connections, just to support different engines and not tie my implementation with MySQL only... I am asking for a best way to do this...

Comment: I would include all dependencies in your POM and change the driver class name and dialect in the config as needed / desired

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion better way would be to use **Profiles**. Please refer to the documentation below.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using spring-boot-starter-parent, you have a list of all popular jdbc drivers with up to date versions.

   ```
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   ```

   Thus, when including dependency, you can omit version:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. You can use maven profiles to specify which jdbc provider to use at
   startup, by previously declaring profile-specific dependencies:

   ```
   <profiles>
       <profile>
           <id>mysql</id>
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>…</dependency>
           </dependencies>
       </profile>
       <profile>
           <id>h2</id>
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>…</dependency>
           </dependencies>
       </profile>
   </profiles>
   ```
3. Then in your config, you can use [@ConditionalOnClass](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html) annotation, to create datasource, based on presence of given class is classpath:

   ```
   @ConditionalOnClass(name ="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource")
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       return new MysqlDataSource();
   }
   ```